# Need help in SQL join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and records in it as below:

```
            User
   ---------------------
         ID     UserId
   ---------------------
          1      User1
          2      User2

          Department_User
   ------------------------------
         ID DEPT_ID       USER_ID
   ------------------------------
          1  1              1
          2  2              1
          3  1              2
```

Now I want a oracle query which will return only those users who are serving in both the departments(1 & 2), in this example it will be 1

Comment: we don't see anything about you tried here. show us what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
select user_id
from department_user
where dept_id in (1, 2)
group by user_id
having count(distinct dept_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select du1.user_id
from department_user du1
where exists (
select *    from department_user du2
where dept_id= 2  on   du1.user_id = du2.user_id);
and du1.dept_id = 1
```

or

```
select user_id
from department_user
where dept_id = 1
and user_id in (
select user_id
from department_user
where dept_id= 2);
```

or

```
select du1.user_id
from department_user du1
join department_user du2 on du1.user_id = du2.user_id
where du1.dept_id=1 and  du2.dept_id = 2
```

I don't know about Oracle but the where exists version is likely the fastest one in SQL Server. The join version is the one you need if you need fields from the record where dept_id = 2 as well as the records where dept_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM
(
SELECT USER_ID, DEPT_ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY USER_ID, DEPT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DEPT_ID) FROM TABLE)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think yous should use "AND" operator in where clause to make sure that select statement satisfies both conditions..try below query...

```
  Select U.ID, U.UserId
  From User U 
  Inner Join Department_User D 
  On U.ID=D.USER_ID 
  Where D.DEPT_ID =1 And D.DEPT_ID = 2
```